# how to update React State while on change

Tags: reactjs

this is my initial state

`const [state, setState] = React.useState({ fleet: {makeId: 867,....}, });`

onChange I need to update the **makeId**.

`setState({...state, ?})`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You tagged redux but your code doesn't mention it. Are you looking for a redux approach?

Comment: no normal state update

Answer (score 3):

You can write something like this,

```
setState({...state, fleet: {...state.fleet, makeId: YourMakeId });
```

That should do the trick.